# Can I get Excel to count based on values in other cells when a date is inputted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I really need help please.

I basically want a sheet that I have created to count how many items are left outstanding. So, I input into one cell if the priority is either H (High), M (Medium), L (Low) which are entered in cells G13:G90. This then feeds into an overview at the top of the sheet. What I then want to be able to do is when a completion date is entered in cells N13:N90 for that to update the total number of completed items based on the information in G13:G90.

My overview has the Priority Rating (H/M/L), No. Completed, Outstanding Issues. So for example, when a date is put into cell N14 and cell G14 is a L, that would mark in the Low Priority of the overview as a completed issue and so on.

I really hope it make sense.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please add some sample data with desired results to help us understanding your issue. (take a screenshot, upload it to e.g. [imgur](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), then post the link in your question; or you can format your data as a table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COUNTIFS` to display the number of each priority that is completed. `=COUNTIFS($G$13:$G$90,"High",$N$13:$N$90,"<>")` You would need to replace the word "high" with whatever you are using to indicate priority, be that a letter, number, or word. The `"<>"` bit is checking that the date column is not blank. If you then want to display total complete, just `SUM` the totals for low medium and high complete.